# C2DM implementation in android

Tags: android, android-c2dm

In my application i want to use C2DM to implement push notifications. For this I am using following code which gets device token or id. I have register for push notification and getting the device id, but my problem is that I am getting multiple device IDs when I run my app again.

Whatever I read from docs it says something like "you will get a unique device token for your app which you can send it to server". So why I am getting multiple device tokens? I don't understand.

Below is my code. Please help.

```
public class RegisterActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    private Context context;
    SharedPreferences preferences;
    Button button;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);


        Log.i("reg key---",""+C2DMBroadcastReceiver.k );


    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(C2DMBroadcastReceiver.k!=null)
        {
            Intent registrationIntent = new Intent("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER");

            registrationIntent.putExtra("app", PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, new Intent(), 0));

            registrationIntent.putExtra("sender", "my email");

            getApplicationContext().startService(registrationIntent);
        }

    }
}


public class C2DMBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private Context context;
    private static String KEY = "c2dmPref";
    private static String REGISTRATION_KEY = "registrationKey";
    public static String k;


    @Override
    public final void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //          // To keep things in one place.
        //          C2DMBaseReceiver.runIntentInService(context, intent);
        //          setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, null /* data */, null /* extra */);      

        this.context = context;
        if (intent.getAction().equals("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION")) {
            handleRegistration(context, intent);
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE")) {
            handleMessage(context, intent);
        }
    }
    private void handleRegistration(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String registration = intent.getStringExtra("registration_id");
        if (intent.getStringExtra("error") != null) {
            // Registration failed, should try again later.
            Log.d("c2dm", "registration failed");
            String error = intent.getStringExtra("error");
            if(error == "SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE"){
                Log.d("c2dm", "SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE");
            }else if(error == "ACCOUNT_MISSING"){
                Log.d("c2dm", "ACCOUNT_MISSING");
            }else if(error == "AUTHENTICATION_FAILED"){
                Log.d("c2dm", "AUTHENTICATION_FAILED");
            }else if(error == "TOO_MANY_REGISTRATIONS"){
                Log.d("c2dm", "TOO_MANY_REGISTRATIONS");
            }else if(error == "INVALID_SENDER"){
                Log.d("c2dm", "INVALID_SENDER");
            }else if(error == "PHONE_REGISTRATION_ERROR"){
                Log.d("c2dm", "PHONE_REGISTRATION_ERROR");
            }
        } else if (intent.getStringExtra("unregistered") != null) {
            // unregistration done, new messages from the authorized sender will be rejected
            Log.d("c2dm=======", "unregistered");

        } else if (registration != null) {
            Log.d("c2dm========", registration);
            SharedPreferences preferences=context.getSharedPreferences("KEY", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            k=preferences.getString("REGISTRATION_KEY",registration);

            Editor editor =
                context.getSharedPreferences(KEY, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
            editor.putString(REGISTRATION_KEY, registration);
            editor.commit();
            // Send the registration ID to the 3rd party site that is sending the messages.
            // This should be done in a separate thread.
            // When done, remember that all registration is done.

        }
    }

    private void handleMessage(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        //Do whatever you want with the message
    }
}
```

Comment: use equals instead of ==... then it might also work..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One time Google says you will get a unique ID, but if you read few more lines google write:

> The application should store this ID for later use. Note that Google
>   may periodically refresh the registration ID, so you should design
>   your application with the understanding that the REGISTRATION Intent
>   may be called multiple times. Your application needs to be able to
>   respond accordingly.

[Read here under 2.](http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/android/c2dm/#register)

So it's not an unique ID. 
I've just tested to push to a device with 2 different registration IDs, both push messages arrived at the device. So it should be no problem. 
The only thing is, that Google maybe delete the registration if after a couple of time.
So you have to call for another one.